# phonegap plugins 5.1.1 cli don't work

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I solved the problem:

"I forgot to read the FAQ. Now, I read it and it worked.

The problem was I was uploading the full project of phonegap instead www directory + config.xml"

I am using Phonegap 5.1.1 cli and when I tested my App with Phonegap Developer App, all plugins such as Dialogs plugin or camera work, but when I compiled the App using Adobe Phonegap Build and installed on the phone, I pressed up a button and the dialog doesn't work:

I have this code on my config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.Mitica.INHISETrrhh" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<name>Control de Acceso INHISET</name>
<description>
    App para realizar los fichajes de la empresa General de Ingenieria INHISET.
</description>
<author email="joaquin.duro@miticatechnology.com" href="http://www.miticatechnology.com">
    Joaquin Duro
</author>
<content src="www/index.html" />
<preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-5.1.1' />
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
<icon src="www/icon.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="www/icon.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="www/icon.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="www/icon.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/icon.png" />
<icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
<icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
<icon gap:platform="webos" src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
<icon gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
<icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" width="640" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

Please, can you help me? Thanks,

Joaquín