# How to install/use cordova plugins?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

I have installed cordova 5.3.3, I create my apps, for android, with:

```
cordova create Project
cd Project
cordova platform add android
```

After that, I zip my file with:

```
cd ..
zip -r Project.zip Project
```

And upload it to phonegap build at:

https://build.phonegap.com/apps

After creating there the apk and instaling it on my android the apps seem the work fine, except when I try to use plugins.
The plugin functions always fail while the rest of the javascript code works fine.

I add plugins has follows:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.vibration
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

And if I list my plugins with:

```
cordova plugin ls
```

I get:

```
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
org.apache.cordova.vibration 0.3.13 "Vibration"
```

I get the same behavior when using phonegap (version 5.3.6), or when just uploading the zip file with only the "www" folder and the "config.xml" file.
I've also read these similar questions in stackoverflow:

[phonegap plugins 5.1.1 cli don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849530/phonegap-plugins-5-1-1-cli-dont-work)

[Cordova plugins not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654231/cordova-plugins-not-working)

But they don't seem to help me in my case.

The index.html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Teste Vibra</h1>
        <button type="button" id="vibrar">Vibrar</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>

</body>
```

The javascript code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    $(function(){
        $( "#vibrar" ).click(function() {
            navigator.vibrate(3000);
            alert("abc");
        });
    })
}
```

I'm using the JQuery library 2.1.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay. You have a fundamental problem. Somehow you have not read the correct documentation.

Please read this to help you get started
Read the **bold** points, then read the body of each section as it applies.

---

#### [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

In this case, you have made mistake #1,

#### I QUOTE:

> **1. Thinking Phonegap is just one system**
>
> There are three similar platforms, Cordova (CLI), Phonegap (CLI), and
>   Phonegag Build and five system (counting Cordova/Phonegap SDK1).
>   People often confuse the three very similar platforms and get tangled
>   in the minor variations that differentiate them.
>
> Oddly enough, the best explanation comes from something built on top
>   of Angular, and wraps the Cordova/Phonegap CLI. - Ionic.
>
> From the Ionic Blog [The Last Word on Cordova and PhoneGap](http://blog.ionic.io/what-is-cordova-phonegap/)
>
> > PhoneGap proper was created around 2009 by a startup called Nitobi as an open source way to access the "native" environment through an embedded Web View in a native app. The goal of the project was to make it possible to build the bulk of a mobile app experience with pure web technologies like HTML5, CSS, and Javascript, but still be able to call into native code when necessary.
> >
> > In 2011 Adobe purchased Nitobi and with it the rights to the PhoneGap brand, and the open source core was donated to the Apache Software Foundation under the name Cordova.
> >
> > Read more on the [Ionic Blog](http://blog.ionic.io/what-is-cordova-phonegap/)

Answer (score 0):

Has stated by JesseMonroy650, I thought phonegap and phonegap build where the same system. But the installation of plugins are made in diferent ways.

example:

- phonegap:
  phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial --save
- phonegap build:
  add the line "`<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial" source="npm" />`" into config.xml

Answer (score 0):

To install and used to Cordova plugin you need to follow the following steps (install simple camera plugin) :

---

### ADD :

Step 1 : 
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera

For Example, if you want to install this plugin into the ionic framework project :

You should write as per below command :

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera

---

### Remove :

To remove the plugin used the following command

Commond:
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-camera